# google gsheets array formula offset (referencing previous row in same column)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula

I am trying to build a simple banking register in gsheets.

Data looks like this:

```
Transaction       Debit   Credit   Balance    Formula
opening balance                    100
first             20               80         D3=D2-B3+C3  
second                     30      110        D4=D3-B4+C4
```

I would like to use array formula, but I am having trouble getting it to handle the reference to another cell in the same column as array formula.

I tried this in cell D3:

```
ArrayFormula(D2:D-B3:B+C3:C)
```

but I get a circular reference error.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell D2, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A2:A),,mmult(transpose(if(transpose(row(B2:C))>=row(B2:C),if(row(A2:A)=2, 100, B2:B*-1+C2:C), 0)),row(B2:C)^0)))
```

Note that the 'startbalance' (100) is coded in the formula. Change if needed.

Comment: Nicely done.  Can you explain what is happening with "if(transpose(row(B2:C))>=row(B2:C)"?

Comment: This part creates a matrix that is then used by MMULT. For more info, check this excellent explanation from Adam. https://docs.google.com/a/open-school.be/spreadsheets/d/1NJPAt5iFQWIyxHx35bpCh6zjVeKon4rdTPk-dfyZDrU/edit#gid=420781522. Make sure to also check the fourth tab (sheet) where you see an example of this part of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

in the same way, a little simpler

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A2:A),,(mmult(1*(transpose(row(B2:C))<=row(B2:C)),C2:C-B2:B))))
```